# Error from reading with ClearCanvas in DICOM file in C# and how to display the DICOM VCR tag

Tags: c#, image-processing, dicom, clearcanvas

I'm receiving an error in runtime using the ClearCanvas libraries. Here is the error

Could not find file 'C:\Users\Don jar\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\DICOMCA\DICOMCA\bin\Debug\Fluro.dcm'.

The error points to this section of the code:

theFile.Load(DicomReadOptions.Default);

I will be grateful for any help. Thanks

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string filename = "Fluro.dcm";
        DicomFile theFile = new DicomFile(filename);
        theFile.Load(DicomReadOptions.Default);
        foreach (DicomAttribute attribute in theFile.DataSet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tag: {0}, Value: {1}", attribute.Tag.Name, attribute.ToString());
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: My main question, since i've been working in VB2010, how do I load the DICOM image in this contex or more appropriately, what is the syntax to call the file from my picture folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename parameter to the constructor to DicomFile sets the absolute path of the DicomFile.  Just set this to the path to a DICOM file in your "picture" folder, as you mention.

The exception you are seeing is caused by the fact that you gave a relative path to the DICOM file, and its just trying to load it in the directory where your application is located.

Comment: Thank you very much Steve, I see it, I had to include the ampersand to call the file. however to display the VR tag in my picturebox. Do I just access it through PictureBox.something etc such as in VB. Thanks